# PHPExcel Export 1022 characters limit in Excel2007

Tags: php, excel, export, dropdown, phpexcel

```
Use PHPExcel to create a dropdown in an excel file:

$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

$configs1 = "Lorem Ipsum is simply, dummy text of the printing, and typesetting 
industry, Lorem Ipsum has been, the industrys standard, dummy text ever, since the 
1500s, when an unknown printer, took a galley of type, and scrambled it to make, a 
type specimen book, It has survived not only ,five centuries, but also the leap ,into 
electronic typesetting, remaining essentially, unchanged, It was popularised, in the 
1960s with the, release of Letraset sheets, containing Lorem Ipsum ,passages, and 
more recently, with desktop publishing, software like Aldus, PageMaker including, 
versions of Lorem Ipsum,Lorem Ipsum is simply, dummy text of the printing, and 
typesetting industry, Lorem Ipsum has been, the industrys standard, dummy text ever, 
since the 1500s, when an unknown printer, took a galley of type, and scrambled it to 
make, a type specimen book, It has survived not only ,five centuries, but also the 
leap ,into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially, unchanged, It was 
popularised, in the 1960s with the, release12345";

$objValidation = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('I2')->getDataValidation();
$objValidation->setType( PHPExcel_Cell_DataValidation::TYPE_LIST );
$objValidation->setErrorStyle( PHPExcel_Cell_DataValidation::STYLE_INFORMATION );
$objValidation->setAllowBlank(false);
$objValidation->setShowInputMessage(true);
$objValidation->setShowErrorMessage(true);
$objValidation->setShowDropDown(true);
$objValidation->setErrorTitle('Input error');
$objValidation->setError('Value is not in list.');
$objValidation->setFormula1('"'.$configs1.'"');

$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
PHPExcel_Settings::setZipClass(PHPExcel_Settings::PCLZIP);
$objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($objPHPExcel);
$result = $objWriter->save($template_save_file);
$objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($objPHPExcel);
```

The below image show 1022 more character and its break dropdown.

[image: Below image show 1022 more character.]

Below image show 1022 character working fine.

[image: Below image show 1022 character working fine.]

The problem is dropdown works fine with 1022 characters after adding more characters dropdown breaks.

How can increase the character limit?

Comment: MS Excel has its limits; and sometimes the only way to increase those limits is to write a "pretty please" letter to Microsoft

But why on earth are you using a DataValidation dropdown with a value that size? You don't seem to be using it for actual DataValidation, but as a Cell comment; so why not actually use a Cell Comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your drop down option to another sheet and get data  from that sheet with below code:

$objValidation->setFormula1('Secondsheet!A2:A100');